# Факторизация (разложение на множители) в SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, факторизация

Например, из числа 12 надо получить список 
[2^2, 3^1] или [2^2, 3]. Как реализовать. Не поделится никто кодом?

Answer (score 2):

Вот простое решение. На самом деле `between` достаточно использовать до округлённого наверх квадратного корня из введённого числа, при условии, что само число тоже проходит проверку. Первый предикат, `factors` возвращает список факторов: `[2,2,2,3,3]`, следующий предикат `count_repetitions` сворачивает список и записывает количество повторений: `[2^3,3^2]`.

```
factors(N,L) :-
    N > 1, !,
    between(2,N,Candidate),
    Rest is N mod Candidate,
    (Rest == 0 ->
         Next is N div Candidate,
         L = [Candidate|L1],
         factors(Next,L1),!).

factors(1,[]).

count_repetitions([], []).
count_repetitions([X|L],CRsN) :-
    count_repetitions(X,L,CR),
    CRsN = [X^CR|CRs],
    remove_all(L,X,Res),
    count_repetitions(Res,CRs).

count_repetitions(_, [], 1).
count_repetitions(X, [Y|L], N) :-
    count_repetitions(X, L, N1),
    (   X == Y -> N is N1 + 1; N = N1).

remove_all([],_,[]).
remove_all([X|Xs],Y,Ys) :-
    Y == X, !, remove_all(Xs,X,Ys).
remove_all([X|Xs],Y,[X|Ys]) :-
    remove_all(Xs,Y,Ys).

answer(N,Factors) :-
    factors(N, L), count_repetitions(L, Factors).
```